# Create mongodb view for sub-collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some collections with sub-collections in them and I need to be able to get sub-collections as they're not sub-collections. Let's say I have collection like that:

```
    [
            {author: "aa", books: [{title:"a", pages: 100}, {title: "b", pages: 200}]},
            {author: "ab", books: [{title:"c", pages: 80}, {title: "d", pages: 150}]}
    ]
```

I want to be able to view this collection like this:

```
    [
            {author: "aa", books.title: "a", books.pages: 100},
            {author: "aa", books.title: "b", books.pages: 200},
            {author: "ab", books.title: "c", books.pages: 80},
            {author: "ab", books.title: "d", books.pages: 150}
    ]
```

Is it possible to create a view as what I need and filter it through web api?

Edit after @mickl 's question:

What I want is show every sub-collection in a new row. I have 2 records in the main collection and 2 sub-collections in every record. So I want to get 4 rows and want to be able to do it on the db side not on the api side.

Comment: Just to clarify: by `"books.title"` you mean nested object "books" or such key with dot in it's name ?

Comment: @mickl I guess such key with dot in it's name. It actually doesn't matter if it has dot or not. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the key thing here is [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) operator which transforms an array of `n` elements into `n` elements with single subdocument.

```
db.createView(
    "yourview",
    "yourcollection",
    [ { $unwind: "$books" } ]
)
```

This will give you a documents in following format:

```
{ author: "aa", books: { title: "a", pages: 100 } },
{ author: "aa", books: { title: "b", pages: 200 } },
{ author: "ab", books: { title: "c", pages: 80 } },
{ author: "ab", books: { title: "d", pages: 150 } }
```

EDIT: to have keys with dots in their names you can run below command:

```
db.createView(
    "yourview",
    "yourcollection",
    [   
        { $unwind: "$books" },
        {
            $project: {
                author: 1,
                books2: {
                    $map: { 
                        input: { $objectToArray: "$books" },
                        as: "book",
                        in: {
                            k: { $concat: [ "books.", "$$book.k" ] },
                            v: "$$book.v"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ { author: "$author" }, { $arrayToObject: "$books2" } ] }
            }
        } 
    ]
)
```

Basically it uses [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to "force" MongoDB to return fields with dots in their names. Outputs:

```
{ "author" : "aa", "books.title" : "a", "books.pages" : 100 }
{ "author" : "aa", "books.title" : "b", "books.pages" : 200 }
{ "author" : "ab", "books.title" : "c", "books.pages" : 80 }
{ "author" : "ab", "books.title" : "d", "books.pages" : 150 }
```

Comment: Unwind works exactly as you said but in the web api I get that unwinded part as BsonDocument and it's 
`books: [ { name: "title", value: "a" }, { name: "pages", value: 100 } ]`

Comment: It probably depends on your data shape, based on what you shared right now it should work fine, check: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xjtKJUMJzIS Is there any chance that you have empty `books` in some documents ?

Comment: Thank you very much, even this solves most of my problem but is there a way I can reach books.title just as I reach author? I really need it to be exactly this way:
`[
            {author: "aa", books.title: "a", books.pages: 100},
            {author: "aa", books.title: "b", books.pages: 200},
            {author: "ab", books.title: "c", books.pages: 80},
            {author: "ab", books.title: "d", books.pages: 150}
    ]`

Comment: @xeon, just modified my answer

Comment: you're a life saver. Thank you very much, this worked.